# UPDATE on UIText table fails

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I am trying to update the UIText Table in a Windows Installer database (.msi)
My program has already updated many tables and fields within the .msi

I am opening the database as such:

```
MsiOpenDatabase(this->MsiFile,MSIDBOPEN_DIRECT,&this->MsiHandle);
```

This returns

> ERROR_SUCCESS

I have updated ~200 records in various tables (Control.Error,Feature,Shortcut,...), all of the updates work.
then I get to:

```
MsiDatabaseOpenView(this->MsiHandle,L"UPDATE UIText SET UIText.Text='Entire 
feature will be unavailable' WHERE (UIText.Key='MenuAbsent')",&ViewHandle)
```

This returns

> ERROR_BAD_QUERY_SYNTAX.

I have tried:

```
L"UPDATE 'UIText' SET 'UIText'.'Text'='Entire feature will be unavailable' 
WHERE ('UIText'.'Key'='MenuAbsent')"
```

and get the same result

> ERROR_BAD_QUERY_SYNTAX.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Darn! Sorry about the waste of time.

```
L"UPDATE UIText SET UIText.Text='Entire...' WHERE (UIText.'Key'='MenuAbsent')
```

Works.

I was confused over the use of 'back ticks'
Key is an SQL reserved word.
UIText.Key is not valid.
UIText.'Key' is also not valid. This is using apostrophes (39 Decimal) around Key.
UIText.`Key` is valid. This is using 'back ticks' (96 Decimal) around Key.